# What is this in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    create! do |success, failure|      
      success.html { redirect_to admin_blogs_path }
    end
```

Seems to be doing alot but where is it....is it part of rails

Comment: Can you give some more hints about the context? In which file is this, what is the class name if there's one etc. Also, it would be nicer if you made your title a tad more descriptive. Something like "What is the create! block in Rails for?". Give us questions to answer. Not riddles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming this is being called in the context of an ActiveRecord model, this doesn't appear to be core. The function of `create!` is to either successfully create the record or throw an exception if a failure occurs. As such, the failure block wouldn't execute.

What it might be is a wrapper around the ActiveRecord object used by an ActionController instance and handles states accordingly. You may want to see where this method is defined in order to get a better sense of what it's doing.

One way to track down mystery methods is this:

```
raise method(:create!).source_location.inspect
```

You'll get an array that lists the source file and source line if it can be resolved.

Comment: i got this NoMethodError (undefined method `source_location' for #<Method:0x7f137e88f890>):
  app/controllers/admin/blogs_controller.rb:12:in `create'
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.10.0.rc1/lib/compass/app_integration/rails/actionpack2/action_controller.rb:7:in `process'
  /home/ubuntu/.bundler/ruby/1.8/client_side_validations-8117b24ce10b/lib/client_side_validations.rb:34:in `call'

Comment: RuntimeError (#<Method: Admin::BlogsController(InheritedResources::Actions)#create!>):

Comment: i got the last one when i did raise method(:create!).inspect

Comment: Ah, I think `source_location` is sadly only a Ruby 1.9 thing then.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed as Matt's comment points out, this functionality is provided by Jose Valim's [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem. This gem provides people with a way of drastically cutting down on the repetition in CRUD controllers by abstracting all the standard crap away into a gem.